# Is the term 'affectation status' generally accepted?

Tags: meaning, phrases, science

The word affectation is defined by Merriam-Webster as:

> a :speech or conduct not natural to oneself :an unnatural form of
>   behavior meant especially to impress others
>
> His French accent is just an affectation.
>
> b :the act of taking on or displaying an attitude or mode of behavior
>   not natural to oneself or not genuinely felt
>
> speaking honestly without affectation
>
> mocked his piety as affectation

Yet the phrase 'affectation status' is often used in a scientific context, eg

> Affectation status and genotypes for the c.1190G>T mutation are indicated [in the pedigree].

([source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257300828_Mutation_of_fibulin-1_causes_a_novel_syndrome_involving_the_central_nervous_system_and_connective_tissues/figures?lo=1))

Is this incorrect? I haven't found any indication of affectation having this meaning, despite the common use of 'affectation status' in human genetics.

Comment: Scientists routinely can and do adopt generic words to have specific technical meanings, within the jargon of a specific discipline.  They don't need anyone's permission, simply the acceptance of their peers.

Comment: Dictionaries tend to focus on the commoner, more everyday usages of terms. You should check this phrase/compound on a science website or in a scientific dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2 archaic The action or process of affecting or being affected.
>   2.1 [count noun] A condition or disease. 'an affection of the skin'  [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affection)

So "affection status" can mean someone who is affected  (or not) by the condition or disease under study. Echoing @HotLicks, it appears to be common usage in some technical circles.

[Here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1070431/) is another example.